# Why can't I see the light source directly?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, eevee-render-engine

I don't understand why I don't see the direct light from light sources. Is there an option to show it? I can't find.

[image: Area light source isn't shown in render view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there is.
To see your lights, just enable *Scene lights* in the *Viewport Shading* menu.

[image]

*Point/Area/Spot* lights don't have any geometry to be displayed. You'll have to use an object with the Emission shader (*Mesh light*) if you want the lightsource visible.

*Scene Lights vs. Mesh light visibility*
[image]

Comment: Thank you! But what is the "visible mass" and why the light sources don't have it? I'd like to use light source instead of emission shader, because as I heard it's faster and makes less noise.

Comment: Light sources don't have any geometry to be displayed - they only *cast* light. Mesh lights might be *slightly* more noisy, but are more physically correct :). Don't worry too much about the noise difference, it's not that big.